# JSON.parse error Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

A problem. Again. Here is the code:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("temporaryArray")){
    var temporaryArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("temporaryArray"));
}else{
    var temporaryArray = [];
}
```

So basically what it does is that when a new page is loaded I don't want to reset the array because later in the code I assign something to this array in localStorage. So what I'm trying to say is that if you can get this item, then when the code is loaded again assign this variable to the localStorage item. Else, just set it to an empty array. But here is the error I'm getting because the array is currently empty(I think that's the reason why):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:61
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: show how you `set` temporaryArray - my guess is, you are not using `JSON.stringify` - because of the `o` in `[object Object]`

Comment: When you set value, use `JSON.stringify`. If not, `[object Object]` will be set and hence `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: *snap* @Rajesh :p

Comment: @Rajesh When I set the values I have been using JSON.stringify

Comment: @Rajesh Hello everyone I've fixed it! It was showing [object Object] for some reason so I went into the console and set the localStorage item to an empty string and now it's fixed. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method invocation fails, it usually helps to look at what the input to the function is. I would recommend doing `console.log(localStorage.getItem("temporaryArray"))` before the `JSON.parse()` call to see what the problem is.

What I would guess the source of the problem is, is that at some point you are calling `localStorage.setItem("temporaryArray",value)` and have forgotten to do JSON.stringify() on the value.